# PHP + ADFS for SSO (via OAuth) - How to setup ADFS?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, adfs3.0

Im trying to use `ADFS` for `SSO` on a project. The project is on `PHP` and Im trying to use `OAuth` for this.

So what are the steps for setting up ADFS to work with OAuth2? I have no idea about ADFS and cant get any direct guide on OAuth2 settings there.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dear Raheel, did I answer your question?

Comment: Dear Vladimir, ive already solved it by another method 2 yrs ago. So I dont know!

Answer (score 2):

> I see that the question is quite old. But in case if other people will
> get here, I have some answer which should be good for March 2019.

Let me start with a general overview.

**SSO**

[SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) could be done with personal Google, Facebook, GitHub, Twitter, Microsoft accounts. After logging in to your account, you can log in to other systems (e.g. WordPress or any other) without password (if other systems integrated with that Identity Provider) and you give the consent (see picture below).

[image: SSO: user consent. Personal Google Account]

There are services whose main focus is to provide Identity Provider / SSO capabilities (e.g. Okta, Auth0, Google Cloud Identity, Azure Active Directory, AWS IAM).

[image: SSO: user consent. Sign in with Microsoft account via Auth0]

In the corporate network, the user could be silently signed in based on the AD account without entering credentials via ADFS.

Actually, ADFS supports different authentication protocols like SAML, WS-Fed, and OAuth. But nowadays usually services implement [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/faq/) which works on top of the [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) protocol.

**OpenID Connect flows**

There is a number of authentication flows that OpenID Connect defines.
Most preferable ones are:

1. `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE` (single-page applications, native applications)

If you are using `oidc-client-js`, you should use `response_type=code` to use PKCE.

> Public native app clients MUST implement the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE RFC7636])
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-6
>
> Note: although PKCE so far was recommended as a mechanism to protect native apps, this advice applies to all kinds of OAuth clients, including web applications.
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-12#section-3.1.1

2. `Implicit flow` considered as **Not recommended**:

> Clients SHOULD NOT use the implicit grant and any other response type causing the authorization server to issue an access token in the authorization response
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-09

3. `Client credentials flow`. For service-to-service communication.

**How to configure ADFS?**

You can find quite detailed documentation with illustrations for "Native app scenario" at [Microsoft Docs: Native client with ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/native-client-with-ad-fs).

If you are not using ADFS, you can play with the PKCE flow setup in the [playground](https://www.oauth.com/playground/authorization-code-with-pkce.html).

**JavaScript frontend**

> **Never** store client secrets in public applications like JS frontend or mobile apps. It's not applicable to PKCE flow but just in case.

If you have a modern SPA application (e.g. Angular or React), it means that frontend should have only `client_id` to enable end-user to obtain the JWT `access_token` in a browser via ADFS. You don't need any `client_secret`.

[oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) could help you with that. Make sure that `code_verifier` is being sent along with a token request (it means that you are using more secured PKCE flow).

**PHP backend**

And on PHP side you'll need to validate the access token. You can implement the workflow on your own according to [that article](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce). But it's better to use OpenID certified library which you can find on this page (not only for PHP):
https://openid.net/developers/certified/

So, for PHP there is only one: [phpOIDC](https://bitbucket.org/PEOFIAMP/phpoidc).

**Authentication**

OAuth 2.0 can help you only with authentication (to identify the user's identity).

Most probably you would like to have different permissions for different users. And OpenID Connect implementation in ADFS provides you the ability to map AD groups to token claims. Therefore, you can decode JWT access token on the backend and implement claims-based authorization.

To use JWT claims be sure to properly validate the authenticity of the token and issuer:

- Validate JWT signature using public key
- Check `issuer` for the proper issuer (Identity Provider)
- Check `aud` (audience) for the proper client ID
- Check `exp` (expiration timestamp)
- Check claims

Comment: Just to note the ADFS now supports PKCE in Windows Server 2019 - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-in-adfs-for-windows-server-2019-a457172e28c3