# ADFS integration with PHP

Tags: php, yii, adfs

I have a PHP application I need to use ADFS for single sign on .

I need to know the basic Concepts of ADFS like what is a relying party ,endpoints whether relying party url is the same as that of the domain of my application and how it is different from endpoint and do I need to provide the xml file to ADFS or relying party url and endpoints work

The other question is how the authentication part would be handled like how the request is going to come like from ADFS ?

Comment: We are not here to do your basic research for you. Even just typing “ADFS PHP” into this site’s search box gives lots of results already, so start by checking what info you can gather from those.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: _“Any article/blog that talks about this would be helpful”_ - that edit doesn’t improve the question, because _“Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. ”_ https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Feel free to ask this on MSDN instead. We can help with more of these sorts of onboarding-style questions there. :) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: That's the Azure AD forum. You want https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=ADFS

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good sample to configure ADFS for single singin in php web app. You can take a [look](https://github.com/schakra/Active-Directory-Sample-for-PHP-Developers)

Active Directory PHP Standalone application is a PHP based web application. This application can be deployed into any of the webserver with the necessary PHP support provided by the webserver. The core functionality of the application is to connect to Active Directory Federation Server (ADFS) configured and authenticate with Active Directory Account. On successful authentication the Application will display the Active Directory Claims received from the ADFS Server. This application uses WS-FEDERATION protocol to communicate with ADFS server.

Prerequsite

1) PHP 5.2 enabled or above with OpenSSL.

2) Web Server (IIS/Apache etc. which has enabled running PHP applications)

3) Access to an ADFS 2.0 server that can have Relying party trust configured for this site.

For other information , you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970377/php-adfs-for-sso-via-oauth-how-to-setup-adfs) thread

Hope it helps.